# How do I change the browser language with Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to access the user browser settings and change the browser language, is this possible using Javascript?

If it's possible, how can I access this? (sample code please)

Comment: Why would you want to change the browsers language?

Comment: i want to use resource bundle in java.

Comment: with the resource bundle feature, the browser can select the language automatically from the browser language. so with editing the browser language i can make a multi language website

Comment: @ammar: Isn't the entire purpose of internationalization with a resource bundle that your application display a number of languages correctly?  Why would you then want to dictate to the user what language they should use?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two different languages

Comment: this feature lets you to discover the user language without asking him about it, but some times the user want to change the language to their language. check google.com, google and facebook uses this ability.

Comment: ammar, see the second part of my answer below

Comment: @ammar: Your last comment confuses me.  Are we really trying to change your users' browser settings or are we just detecting their setting in order to choose the right resource bundle in your Java app?  Google.com, and google aren't different things (facebook is), and they aren't Java applications, and they don't change your browser settings for you.

Comment: i mean google and facebook using the resource bundle. but how they change the language manually i don't know. and be sure that google is java java and java but about facebook seams to be php, but that looks like a joke, but i think that facebook is java too

Comment: @ammar: Confusion monotonically increasing.  Parse error detected.  You want me to be sure that... 1) google is java java *AND* java; 2) the fact that facebook is php is a joke; 3) you know that facebook uses a resource bundle, but you only *think* that facebook is java?

Comment: I am interested in the same thing. We are using Date.toLocaleString() to print the current date/time, but even when the rest of the page is in French and <html lang="fr"... Javascript insists on printing the date in English if the browser's first language preference is English. I which the Javascript engine would localize itself to match the page language! :(

Comment: @Lekensteyn - for testing. I think browsers should allow JavaScript to change the language setting when the page is served from localhost. It's a PIA to test and change the language setting when one wants to support multiple locales.

Answer (score 12):

You can detect, but cannot set.

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

// navigator.language     : Netscape & Firefox
// navigator.userLanguage : Internet Explorer
```

If you want to output different languages, the best way is to do it server-side.  Either:

- use an AJAX call to dynamically load the appropriate page
- use a session variable to load the initial page correctly

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible and a bad idea.  A better idea is to detect the browser's language, which is possible to do reasonably well, and ask the user to change it (assuming the change is absolutely necessary).

Comment: Neither is changing a user's browser language.

Comment: @Andrew Dunn, @ammar, only this is user friendly: everything the user wants must be gathered from the user's brain using nanomachines inside their blood which are wirelessly connected to my server that has a good AI, which can also predict the user's expectations. Fees may apply and this might be against your jurisdiction's laws.

Answer (score 5):

No that is not possible. How would you find it if you open a page, and your browser turns Arabic (or some other language you can't read)?

Comment: If this would happen I'd find this pretty awesome, as it means the impossible has been achieved.

Comment: I'ld be worried and wonder what vulnerability has been abused.

Comment: You are thinking in web-pages and not in web-applications. How would you find it if you open a web-application, and your (Arabic)browser shows Arabic, while your web-application user-profile is English?

Answer (score 4):

This is possible if you do it from within a Chrome extension.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52455776/9430588) to a similar question & [`contentScript.js`](https://github.com/athyuttamre/locale-switcher/blob/master/contentScript.js) of [locale-switcher Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc/related):

```js
let locale = null;

chrome.storage.local.get(["locale"], result => {
  if (result) {
    locale = result.locale;
  }

  if (locale) embedScript();
});

const embedScript = () => {
  const code = `
    (() => {
      Object.defineProperties(Navigator.prototype, {
        language: {
          value: '${locale}',
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: true,
          writable: false
        },
        languages: {
          value: ['${locale}'],
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: true,
          writable: false
        }
      });
    })();`;

  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.textContent = code;
  document.documentElement.prepend(script);
  script.remove();
};
```

I'm aware of timing (this question was asked 10 years before this answer) & that would be particularly fun if you are the author of this extension.

Comment: How is this done with V3?

Answer (score 2):

If what you actually want to do is detect the language the user is using, which is what you want to do, because nothing will annoy your visitors more that their browser preferences getting changed, on the server-side, read the `Accept-Language` HTTP request header that all modern browsers send, it should contain all the info you need. If it is absent, assume the language of your largest audience.

Check out [RFC2616 Section 14.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more information on `Accept-Language` and it's use.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not possible using JavaScript on a web page.

A browser Extension might have the rights to change this - I'm not sure, it will also depend on the browser. However, building such an extension would require a fair amount of skill and work.