# How to change Chrome settings to test using navigator.language?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internationalization, locale, navigator

I'm trying to internationalize an app and need to test how it behaves in other locales.

However, `navigator.language` always returns `en-US`, even if I change language settings in both Chrome and OS X.

What can I do to the browser to force `navigator.language` to return something like `es-MX`?

**Clarification**

I'm trying to make the change as a user, through the GUI, not with code.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753999/how-do-i-change-the-browser-language-with-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Sept 2021, on Mac (M1):

##### To change `window.navigator.language`:

1. Settings > Advanced > Language > Add Language
2. then bring this language to the top

#### To change the language of the user interface:

(thanks to @AdamBittlingmayer above)

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleLanguages '(es, es-ES)'
```

To verify:

```
defaults read com.google.Chrome
```

Answer (score 27):

Use chrome://settings/languages#lang and (important) make sure that the language you selected is the **top** choice (the preferred language).

More information: https://alicoding.com/detect-browser-language-preference-in-firefox-and-chrome-using-javascript/

Answer (score 14):

On MacOS, the Chrome UI language (`window.navigator.language`) cannot be set via chrome://settings/languages or even via the `--lang` command line argument (like on Windows) or environment variables (like on Linux).

The browser accept languages (`window.navigator.languages` array, note the final *s*) can be set via chrome://settings/languages and thus via ChromeDriver options.

Therefore, besides manually changing the system language for the OS user, the only option remaining is the `-AppleLanguages` flag.

For example, to Spanish:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleLanguages '(es, es-ES)'
```

To verify:

```
defaults read com.google.Chrome
```

This is the situation as of Chrome build 58.0.3029.110.

Answer (score 4):

With **Sensors** on [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) as shown below, you can test how [navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language) behaves in other locales. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221494/how-to-change-the-locale-in-chrome-browser#69149258) explaining **Sensors** in detail.

[image]