# How to change the locale in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, plugins, locale

I want to change Accept-language request header to anything I wanted in chrome, is there any extension or plugin where I can do it. I want to be able to change locale and language both. Main requirement is changing the locale.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Open chrome, go to chrome://settings/languages

On the left, you should see a list of languages. Use mouse to drag the language you want to the top, that will change the order for the values in Accept-language of requests.

If you still don't see the language you prefer, it may be cookies. Go to cookies and clean it up you should be good.

Comment: This worked for me. Just remember to close and restart Chrome.

Comment: Drag-and-drop is no longer a thing in the language settings... which is sad. But there's a "move to top" option which accomplishes what you want, I suppose (switching the primary locale).

Comment: Does not work for the purpose asked as noted in comments to other answer.

Answer (score 164):

### July, 2023 Update:

On Chrome, press **F12** to open **Developer Tools**:

[image]

Then, press **Esc** to open **another panel** which has **Sensors** tab:

[image]

Finally, selecting **Location** like `Tokyo` can set **Locale** `ja-JP` temporarily as shown below, then you can test a page by reloading the page. I use this function for testing **internationally launched website**:

[image]

If there isn't **Sensors** tab, you can open it from **the 3 dots** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can change the locale by setting the 1st language which is used to display websites as shown below. *You can go to the page with `chrome://settings/languages`:

[image]

Comment: The "extra panel" for me only has these tabs: `Console`, `Network conditions`, `Issues`.

Chrome 113.0.5672.92 on a Mac.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/sensors/#open-sensors

Depending on your operating system, press the following to open the Command Menu:

On MacOS, Command+Shift+P
On Windows, Linux, or ChromeOS, Control+Shift+P

Comment: after change location to London, will it apply to the webpage immediately? When I change the location nothing change.

Comment: @Mark Not immediately. You need to reload the page.

Comment: Thanks. I tried refresh and still nothing change. Maybe the site is not responsive to Location

Answer (score 21):

Based from this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/478565/chrome-extension-for-switching-locale-accept-languages), you need to bookmark `chrome://settings/languages` and then Drag and Drop the language to make it default. You have to click on the **Display Google Chrome in this Language** button and completely restart Chrome.

Comment: It is just changing the language, the locale is still going as en_US only. I wanted to control the locale part Accept-Language header.

Answer (score 11):

To see what's your current locale, do

```js
Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale
```

in Dev Tools > console.  ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42070353))

---

The top answer here is both outdated, and does NOT work in Mac OS (November 2021).

The official answer is available at:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/#how-to-set-browsers-locale

## Windows: Using the UI

Here's how to change the locale using the UI on Google Chrome for Windows:

- App icon > Options
- Choose the Under the Hood tab
- Scroll down to Web Content
- Click Change font and language settings
- Choose the Languages tab
- Use the drop down to set the Google Chrome language
- Restart Chrome

## Mac OS X

To change the locale on Mac, you use the system preferences.

- From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences
- Under the Personal section, choose International
- Choose your language and location
- Restart Chrome

## Linux

To change the locale on Linux, first quit Google Chrome. Then, all in one line, set the LANGUAGE environment variable and launch Google Chrome. For example:

```
LANGUAGE=es ./chrome
```

## Chrome OS

To change the locale on Chrome OS:

- From the system tray, choose Settings.
- Under the Languages and input section, choose the Language dropdown.
- If your language is not listed, click Add languages and add it.
- Once added, click the the 3-dot More actions menu item next to your language and choose Display Chrome OS in this language.
- Click the Restart button that appears next to the set language to restart Chrome OS.

Comment: can also do ```navigator.language```

Answer (score 7):

[on hold: broken in Chrome 72; reported to work in Chrome 71]

The "Quick Language Switcher" extension may help too:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie

The *Quick Language Switcher* extension allows the user to supersede the locale the browser is currently using in favor of the value chosen through the extension.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Currently this nice extension is not working with Chrome 72.
So right now for me the "fastest" way to switch language is to go directly in: chrome://settings/languages

Answer (score 4):

Use [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/related?hl=ru) Chrome extension.

[image]

Or you can try more complex value like Accept-Language: `en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,th;q=0.7`

Comment: Did not work for me, Google search results are still not in English.

Comment: @DmitryKarpenko Try checking what your Accept-Language header is at a site like this: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending.  

You can also try searching Google from an incognito tab.  Most Google products are going to ignore your Accept-Language header if you're logged in and "guess" your language preferences based on prior interactions with search. (Note: you can force change this here https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1#languages)

Comment: @DmitryKarpenko Check out my answer below for a way to do this without any extension.

Comment: @lbragile , for now I'm using VPN to get proper language (or rather location) search results, but your trick looks interesting and less of an overkill. Thanks, I'll try it!

Answer (score 4):

There is an article written by the devtools team describing how change the location settings in Chrome for testing purposes: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/geolocation

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found, summarized in a few pictures:

[image: Adding Language]

[image: Changing Language]

[image: Relaunch]

You could skip a few steps (up to step 4) by simply navigating to `chrome://settings/languages` right away.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but I was searching for a solution to define language for chrome without even starting it or update the exe shortcut.

It is possible to force a language and a locale for chrome with the registry on windows.

You need 2 keys to be changed **WITH ADMIN RIGHTS** :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"ApplicationLocaleValue"="fr"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome\ForcedLanguages]
"1"="fr-FR"
```

This is forcing the language so **all users will not be able to update it with the Chorme UI**.

If you need to force a language and be able to modify it with the UI, maybe there is a solution on the official Documentation linked below.

Official Documentation :

- [ApplicationLocaleValue](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ApplicationLocaleValue)
- [ForcedLanguages](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ForcedLanguages)

Best regards.