# Is there a way to change locale on a browsing using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, locale

I am looking at way to set window.navigator.language programmatically. I was wondering if there was a way to do this using angularjs ?

Currently, I am using localization service to switch get my localization with i18n.

Comment: Since it's a browser setting it's a ready only property. You could ask a user to change it via preferences or similar but it cannot be set programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753999/how-do-i-change-the-browser-language-with-javascript

Comment: Not directly.  See this [SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) for inspiration.

Comment: no, but wherever your code looks there, you can look at another property (of your making) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the browser language with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753999/how-do-i-change-the-browser-language-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: **No**

Locale should be set by the browser and is typically [read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator).

There may be ways to mess with the browser to change this, but if this could be done with just JavaScript that would potentially be a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to change the user's browser language then I think you're doomed due to all the security things... However, if your intention is to change the language for the Accept-Language header in web requests you have a better case.

For the latter - check out Angulars `$httpProvider.interceptors`.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
     'request': function(config) {
            config.headers['Accept-Language'] = 'some locale';
            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

Good luck :)